# Structs with pointer to next struct?

Tags: c, list, struct

I want to have a session where I insert totally 10 different integers in the **size** variable that is inside the linked list. I believe I should use result_register() for this?

When all 10 integers are stored I want to print them out by typing **result->size**.

I am new with linked lists so please be gentle.

```
struct result {   
    int size;
};

struct result* result_next()
{
   // What do I type here?
}

void result_register(int size)
{
    // What do I type here?
}
```

**main**

```
struct result* result;

while ((result = result_next()))
    printf("%d\n", result->size);
```

Then I want to be able to print out the results by doing like above.

Comment: Why are you using the same name for struct and pointer to it? If you google you will find tones of examples for linked lists

Comment: shouldn't it be `struct result {   
        int size;
        struct result *next;
    };` ?

Comment: Seriously? [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380), and consider how something as simple as typing "C linked list" in a search bar could apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

You're result should have a `next` pointer to point to the next node in the linked list:

```
struct result {   
    int size;
    struct result *next;
};
```

Then, assuming you've got a pointer the head you just walk the list;

```
struct result *node = head;

while(node != null)
{
  printf("%d\n", node->size);
  node = node->next;
}
```

To create a new item in the list you need something like this:

```
struct result *Add(struct result *head, int size)
{
  struct result *newHead = (struct result*)malloc(sizeof(struct result));
  newHead->size = size;
  newHead->next = head;

  return newHead;
}
```

Now you can say:

```
struct head *head=add(null, 0);
head *head=add(head, 1);
head *head=add(head, 2);
head *head=add(head, 3);
```

This will give you a linked list with `3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0`