# typedef struct what meant by making pointer next pointing node?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

cant understand this line of code `node *Next;`

```
typedef struct Node_type node;

struct Node_type{
    u32 value;
    node *Next;
};
```

Comment: Please edit your question with more than just code, and format that code properly.

Comment: Also, look up the concept of linked lists.

Comment: As a side note, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650205/structs-with-pointer-to-next-struct) is marked as duplicate, but the one of which it is a duplicate is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered the question itself in your question. It’s just a pointer to another ‘Node_type’ or it’s name alias ‘node’. That means you can assign it an address of another one of that type whether it be local storage on the stack or dynamically allocated memory on the heap.